# Como modificar datos específicos de un archivo .txt con Python

Tags: python

tengo estos datos en un archivo texto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
quisiera poder sumar o resta la cantidad cuando se hace la transferencia, cambiar valor y cambiar código.
Este es mi código:

```
moneda = input("Digite el nombre de la criptomoneda: ")
            while not esmoneda(moneda):
                print("Moneda Invalida.")
                moneda=input("Ingrese el nombre de la moneda: ")
            else:
                cant = float(input("Digite la cantidad de "+moneda+" : "))
                while cant>100 or cant<0:
                    print("Cantidad no puede ser inferior a cero y superior 100")
                    cant = float(input("Digite la cantidad de "+moneda+" : "))
                else:
                    codigo = float(input("Digite el codigo: "))
                    while (codigo==180695):
                        print("El codigo no puede ser el mismo del usuario")
                        codigo = float(input("Digite el codigo: "))
                    else:
                        dataP = mostrarBalanceMoneda(moneda).json()
                        precioU = float(round(dataP["data"][moneda]["quote"]["USD"]["price"],2))
                        totalCripto = cant*precioU

                        nombre_archivo = "registro.txt"
                        archivo = open(nombre_archivo,"r")

                        texto = archivo.read()
                        archivo.close()
                        lineas = texto.splitlines()
                        terminos = texto.split("=")
                        diccionario={}
                        for linea in lineas:
                            termino = linea.split("=")
                            diccionario[termino[0]]=termino[1]

                        buscar = moneda
                        encontrado = diccionario.get(buscar)

                        if encontrado:
                            print(buscar+":"+" "+encontrado)
                            print(encontrado)
                        else:
                            dia=date.today()
                            archivo = open(nombre_archivo,"a")
                            archivo.write("\n"+str(moneda)+"={ Cantidad:"+str(cant)+"Precio total:"+str(totalCripto)+"Codigo:"+str(codigo)+"}")
                            archivo.close()

                            def crearArchivo():
                                archivoT = open("transacciones.txt", "a")
                                archivoT.write("Transaccion Criptomeneda:"+str(moneda)+" Cantidad: "+str(cant)+" Precio total: "+str(totalCripto)+" Codigo: "+str(codigo)+" Realizada: "+dia.strftime("%A %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S"))
                                archivoT.close

                            crearArchivo()
                            print("Los Datos ingresados fueron: ")
                            print("Criptomeneda: "+str(moneda)+" Cantidad: "+str(cant)+" Precio total: "+str(totalCripto)+" Codigo: "+str(codigo))
```

El codigo crea dos archivos, una para saber transferencia o el otro para el registro de la moneda, si la moneda no existe se debe crear, de lo contrario se debe modificar la cantidad sumando o restando y modificar el precio y el código

Comment: claramente tienes una muy mala estructura de tu txt y se deben de usar expresiones regulares

Comment: cuales deberia usar

Comment: te refieres a la expresión regular o a la estructura de tu archivo??

Answer (score 0):

Usar el módulo csv de python sería mejor para guardar valores en un archivo de texto:

```
import csv

csvfile = open('registro.csv', mode='a')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
csv_writer.writerow([moneda, cant, totalCripto, codigo])

csvfile.close()
```

Los datos en el archivo registro.csv se guardan asi:

```
BTC,2,4,7
ETH,6,8,0
```

Y luego para leer el archivo se usa:

```
cf = open('registro.csv', 'r')
csv_reader = csv.reader(cf, delimiter=',')
d = dict()
for row in csv_reader:
    d[row[0]] = [float(item) for item in row[1:]]
cf.close()
```

El diccionario creado tiene la forma:

```
d = {'BTC': [2.0, 4.0, 7.0], 'ETH': [6.0, 8.0, 0.0]}
```

Comment: me gusta la idea de proponer la otra estructura (aunque no la librería) pero no estas resolviendo el problema del AP, si su programa escribe o modifica los datos con la estructura que ya tienen tendría que cambiar y rediseñar todo su programa para adaptar tu solución. Yo habría dado la respuesta a la pregunta que se plantea (sin modificaciones) y luego proponer una mejor estructura :)